# Android get data from the parse table (json file) (imported in parse.com-data browser)

Tags: android, json, parsing, object, parse-platform

I have one json file, that I imported in parse.com->data browser->import partition. I can get the String and image value from the table but I have no idea about how to get following values. First column have name chapters of type array look like one field following,

```
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Chapter","objectId":"BCr3uAnapV"}]
```

how to get above value and second column have, name user of type object look like following,

```
{"password":"xxx"}
```

Please any one help me for above, I have tried Googling but it did not help.

EDIT:
See following screen shot: arrow display column 1) chapter and have another column 2) user I want to fetch (get ) that for e.g. if we want to get data of String type like: `String provider = (String) objectList.get(i).get("provider");` this manner this way I want to above data, below my screen shot:

[image]

Comment: what exactly you want... a web service for fetching data from server ...and pass this url in your java file where you want..

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "how to get above value and second column have,name user of type object look like following,"

Comment: What is the name of the class displayed in the above image?

Comment: class  named of above class is "author"

Answer (score 0):

This line is a relation (of type Pointer) to another Class in Parse:

```
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Chapter","objectId":"BCr3uAnapV"}]
```

The class being Chapter. You can make sure this object is fetched together with the object pointing to it using "include":

```
query.include("chapter");
```

When you query for the other object, using `query.include` on pointer relations will ensure these related objects are fetched as well.

Comment: hellow Mr.Handsomeguy , see my edited questions.thank for reply